# Cocos2d sprite file finding

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I am looking for a way to find the filename of the CGSprite variable, then use it in an IF statement. Like this:

```
if(target.spritefilename?? == @"Car1.png")
{
    target = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Car1_dead.png" rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 37, 76)];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure why you want to do this. But as far as I am guessing your purpose I would like to suggest an alternative and proper way to identify your different sprites.

There is a "userData" property in the sprite (inherited from parent) which you can use to store your custom data. So when you create your sprites you should also assign the identified to the userData property.

Like in your case when you first create your "target" sprite, you can then set, "target.userData = "

Later you can check if target.userData is equal to your required file name.

This is the proper way to store custom data in your sprites.

I hope it helps.

Comment: see what i need to know is how to find what car bumped into the player. i have at least 6 cars on the map at once, and need to know how to find the car that hit him, to change its sprite, and same with the players sprite

Comment: I assume you already have "Collision Detection" logic implemented. So when you create 6 cars and load your sprites for each of the car. You should also put the fileName or some other identified (e.g Car-ID) in userData field. So whenever your object "Collide" you can check if object.userData == "car-1" then you should load the "car-1-dead" sprite in that object. If you are still confused, please let me know how you are loading sprites and how you are detecting collisions so that I can try to explain according to your code.

Answer (score 2):

```
if([target.spritefilename isEqualtoString:@"Car1.png"])
```

is what i guess you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **isEqualtoString** for string comparison.

```
if([target.spritefilename isEqualtoString:@"Car1.png"])
```

For [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).

Answer (score 0):

store the sprite names in an array and check the current sprite name matches the name in an array.

```
if([image_array containsObject:@"car.png"])
{
NSLog(@"Image Found");
}
```

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
If([sprite.userData hasPrefix@"Car1"])
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if([(NSString*)sprite.userData hasPrefix@"Car1"])
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose of this to just identifying the sprite you can simply do it by using tag property of sprite.

Like set a taf for sprite while initialing or creating the sprite as

```
CCSprite *spr1=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"1.png"];
spr1.tag=1;

CCSprite *spr2=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"2.png"];
spr2.tag=2;
```

and while getting the sprite on particular event use to get tag value as

```
if([(CCSprite*)tagetSprite tag]==1)
{
}
else if([(CCSprite*)tagetSprite tag]==2)
{
}
```